# wlan interface is missing in ifconfig but present in the iwconfig

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, wlan

I have OrangePi Plus 2 with lubuntu installed and try to setup wifi there. Wlan interface is missing in the if config, but present in the iwconfig.

ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 1e:ee:98:39:b4:ef  
***
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
***
```

iwconfig

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan6     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

tunl0     no wireless extensions.

wlan1     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

rfkill list all

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy1: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Can somebody point me there the problem could be? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try ifconfig -a.  Typically ifconfig alone won't show interfaces that are not "up".